# Surround chapter number with horizontal rules

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, rules

I want to format my chapter headings so they look something like this:

> ------ 1 --------------------------------- % horizontal rule here
>
> Here is the title for chapter 1
>
> ------------------------------------------ % horizontal another rule

I can use the `titlesec` package to create most of this, but I can't get the first line I want, i.e. the chapter number surrounded by raised horizontal rules. I can almost get it right with \hrulefill using:

```
\hrulefill\thechapter \hrulefill\hrulefill
```

but the rule produced is at baseline height, and I cannot figure out how to raise the \hrulefill command. On the internet I stumbled on an alternative by using leaders:

```
\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leavevmode\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill\kern0pt}
```

but this also does not produce quite what I want. It successfully raises the line, but the result looks more like a series of concatenated small lines(of 1pt length, I guess), instead of a unified rule. I've tried to reduce the size of the individual units by setting it to something like `\rule[#1]{0.1pt}` but that seems to significantly slow down the rendering of my PDF viewer (in one instance it even crashed it). I'm not sure why.

I've also tried the `xhfill` package, but including two `xrfill` commands next to each seems to introduce a small gap between them.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, either by modifying \hfillrule or introducing some other commands ?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}


% I've tried two ways of defining the rule... 
% I've tried this option:
\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leavevmode\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill\kern0pt}
\newcommand{\chaphrfill}{\raisedrule[10pt]{5pt}}

% And I've also tried this: 
\usepackage{xhfill}
\newcommand{\chaphrfill}{\xrfill[10pt]{5pt}}


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\scshape}
{%
  \hspace*{0em}
{\chaphrfill~~\thechapter~~\chaphrfill\chaphrfill}
 }
 {0em}
 {\Large\raggedright#1}    


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title....}
 text .....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of whatt you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ti*K*z, like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\scshape}
{%
 \hspace*{-0.5em}
{\tikz \draw [line width=2mm](0,0)--(2,0)node[fill=white, right,
shift=({0cm,1cm})]{\scalebox{10} \thechapter}--(\textwidth,0);}
 }
 {-1em}
{\Large\raggedright#1 
\hspace*{-0.5em}
{\tikz \draw [line width=2mm](0,0)--(\textwidth,0);}}    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title....}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, it didn't even occur to me to consider tikz (probably because I have no experience with it). This might be what I need. Is there any way I can control the vertical position of the top line, however ? The font size of the number "\thechapter" that I'm using is significantly bigger, and I want to be able to specify exactly where it should meet with the line....

Comment: If I understand you right, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a hammersledge like TikZ to crack this nut. Is it  something like this you're after?

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{headingcolour}{Silver!50!Lavender}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\scshape}
{\color{headingcolour}\rule[1.5ex]{0.2\textwidth}{4.5pt}~~\scalebox{4}{\thechapter}~~\rule[1.5ex]{\linegoal}{4.5pt}}
 {2ex}
 {\LARGE\filright#1}[\vskip1.5ex\leavevmode{\color{headingcolour}\titlerule[4.5pt]}]
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*1}{*25}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title....}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: Something like it, but there are a couple of issues with this solution. I don't need the number centered, but about 1/3 or 1/4 of the way to the left, and I could not achieve that with \xrfill. Second, the color on the rules is not uniform. It looks more like individual dashes stringed together.

Comment: I've posted a variant, no more using `xhfill`, but only the standard `\rule`, and `titlerule`. I'm using the `linegoal` package, which measures the distance from the end of the current line, but requires two compilations.

Comment: This works. Thank you.